# Prove two covariance matrices have same eigen values?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

There are two covariance matrices $U$ and $V$ such that $U= X^\top X$ and $V = XX^\top$ where $X$ is a $d\times N$ matrix. How can I prove that $U$ and $V$ have the same non-zero eigenvalues?

Comment: You mean, _nonzero_ eigenvalues.

Comment: Duplicate of this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30072/singular-values-of-transpose-same

Comment: thanks for the reply. I went through the other question but found it very difficult for me. I am a beginner. Can u please explain in simple terms?

Answer (score 0):

This should really be a comment- but I have too low reputation to make a comment. Hence I am writing it as an answer.

It's a very standard theorem in liner algebra that for two matrices A and B, AB and BA have the same non zero eigenvalues. Take A=$X^T$, and B= X to get your result.