# How to sample a singular matrix-variate normal distribution?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normal-distribution, sampling, svd

**What is known**

The wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_normal_distribution#Drawing_values_from_the_distribution) for the matrix-variate normal distribution has a section on how to efficiently sample from it *without* using the Kronecker product (which is computationally prohibitive in this case). To summarize, given the Cholesky decomposition of two positive definite covariance matrices $C = AA^{T}$ and $D = B^{T}B$ and a random sample from the standard normal $X$ (with the corresponding dimensions), a sample from the matrix-variate normal distribution is efficiently obtained via $Y = AXB$.

**The problem**

In the case of singular covariance matrices, due to linearly related samples or features in $Y$, it is not possible to perform the Cholesky decomposition. In a multivariate normal setting one would simply resolve this by:

> taking a standard normal distribution, rescaling and rotating it, and
>   finally embedding it isometrically into an affine subspace of a higher
>   dimensional space. Algebraically, this is simply done
>   by means of a singular value decomposition ([see here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/159322/107160)).

However, in the case of a matrix-variate normal it is not clear how to proceed.

Simply exchanging the Cholesky decompositions for an SVD style square    root operation does not seem to yield correct results ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_normal_distribution#Expected_values))    $-$ possibly because of the difference between $AA^{T}$ and $B^{T}B$     in requiring the lower and upper triangular matrix of the Cholesky       decomposition respectively and therefore some inherent difference to     the SVD approach.

**Potential solution**

It's not possible to have $Y$ and $Y^{T}$ yield the       standard deviations that were initially specified and from which       (together with the respective correlation matrices) the covariance       matrices were initially generated. Since, the       expected covariances of $Y$ are different from $C$ and $D$ due to the    additional trace($C$) and trace($D$) factors ([see    here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_normal_distribution#Expected_values)).

---

Page 69 of this [book](https://books.google.ca/books?id=PQOYnT7P1loC&printsec=frontcover&dq=matrix%20variate%20distributions&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjV0-jCgsnPAhXBWBQKHXjwCxwQ6wEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=matrix%20variate%20distributions&f=false) may be helpful and this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30072/singular-values-of-transpose-same).